# Is there a difference between resize fromEvent to HostListener in angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular, Is there a difference between

```
  resize$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize')
```

to:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  event.target.innerWidth;
}
```

in terms of performance?

Comment: Not directly I suspect, although with the HostListener it needs to invoke the callback function (a lot), which is probably more intensive then converting it to an RxJs stream (like with fromEvent). Depending on the usage of this resize event, the fromEvent is probably easier as you can debounce those events with a debounceTime operator and therefore limit the number of events your code has to handle in response to the resize.

Answer (score 0):

I think in terms of performance, it's better to use `fromEvent` with the `debounceTime` operator to execute the logic inside the handler sporadically during resizing (maybe 100-1000ms, which is good from a performance point of view), not continuously (every millisecond).

```js
// The value is emitted every 500ms during the resize.
resize$ = fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(debounceTime(500));
```